# #1146 table 'db.tablename' doesnt exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I use AMPPS for localhost server purpose. I was working on one of my client site on localhost.

When I start working the other day, it suddenly starts giving me such error

[image]

**table does not exist** Even though I can clearly see tables on left-hand sidebar as you can see in the attached image.

If I click on columns in table, it shows such error.

[image]

Comment: may be files of the tables got corrupted.

Comment: how can it get corrupted..? Is there any solution for that..?

Comment: will you please run the `show tables` command in sql section.

Comment: try this link . this can sort out your problem https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133481/cannot-open-some-tables-in-phpmyadmin